# nvimのディレクトリにconfigがない？

Tags: ubuntu, vim, neovim

## 環境

WSL2上でUbutntu動かしてます。

Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
WSL バージョン: 1.2.5.0
カーネル バージョン: 5.15.90.1
WSLg バージョン: 1.0.51
MSRDC バージョン: 1.2.3770
Direct3D バージョン: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore バージョン: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows バージョン: 10.0.22621.1778

## 概要

以下の記事を参考にAstroNvimの導入を試みています。

[AstroNvim のインストール | VSCodeが物足りない人へ AstroNvimの紹介](https://zenn.dev/chot/articles/72bc7dfbec3b33#astronvim-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

「AstroNvimのインストール」の項で `$ cd .config/` を実行しようとしたんですが、そんなものはないと表示されました。

## ディレクトリ構造

```
nvim
.
├── BACKERS.md
├── BSDmakefile
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakePresets.json
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MAINTAIN.md
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── build
├── ci
├── cmake
├── cmake.config
├── cmake.deps
├── cmake.packaging
├── contrib
├── runtime
├── scripts
├── src
└── test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.config` が存在しなければ作成しましょう。

[AstroNvim](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim) リポジトリのインストール手順を見ると、既存の `~/.config/nvim` をバックアップしてから作業を進めていますが、今回は Neovim 自体も新規インストールなので `~/.config` が存在しない状態なのだと思います。
(参照している解説記事ではこの部分を考慮し忘れている気がします)

> ```
> mv ~/.config/nvim ~/.config/nvim.bak
> mv ~/.local/share/nvim ~/.local/share/nvim.bak
> ```

もう一点、参考にした記事では (ビルド用に `git clone` した) `neovim` の下に `.config` があるかのような記述になっていますが、こちらも恐らく誤りです。

---

対応として、以下のようにまず `mkdir` で `~/.config` を作成してから `git clone` を実行してみてください。

```
mkdir ~/.config
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim ~/.config/nvim
```